# Using Strings in Java Lists

Tags: java, string, list

I know that Java has an idiomatic behavior about String manipulation. Because strings are immutable we can not change the contents. So we can not write:

```
String s="test;"
s.toUpperCase();
```

We need to assign the result of s.toUpperCase() to a new variable like:

```
String s1="test";
String s2=s1.toUpperCase;
```

`s1.toUpperCase` is not the the string `s1` that changed to uppercase. It is a new string with its own memory location.
So `s1` and `s2` refer to two completed different memory locations with two copies of "test" and "TEST" literature.
But if we don't want to use a new variable to assign the new string then we can do this:

```
String s="test";
s=s.toUpperCase();
```

The question:
Can we do the same with a List? The s variable represents a memory location that has the value of "test". So in the `s=s.toUpperCase();` we drive the `s` to point to the new address of the created string `s.toUpperCase()` . If in a `List<String> list` the `list.get(0)` point (like `s`) to a location of string why we can't do the same as `s` like: `list.get(0)=list.get(0).toUpperCase()` or any other way for example like arrays work:

```
String[] array={"test1","test2"};
array[0]=array[0].toUpperCase();
```

Comment: `list.get(0)` does _return_ a value, so you can't assign anything to it. Of course you can use `list.set(0, list.get(0).toUpperCase())` etc.

Comment: Because of encapsulation. list.get(idx) has been designed to return a value at a particular index. You can't make it do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`list.get(0)=list.get(0).toUpperCase()` is forbidden by Java grammar and semantic.

Roughly (details are more complex, see [15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26) for more details), the left hand part of an assignment must be a variable (or a field). But  `list.get(0)` is not, it is a value, thus you have to use some method that will lets you modify the value of the corresponding element of the list:

```
list.set(0, list.get(0).toUpperCase())
```

Comment: I see... so there is no way to work in string List like Array string:
String[] array={"test1","test2"};
array[0]=array[0].toUpperCase();

Comment: and what is "value"? The returned thing isn't a String? A String is an object and not an abstract thing like "value".

Comment: 3 is a value, do you think that can be changed? Make a difference between a value and the box that stores it...

Comment: 3 is a convenient-cheating option because it is primitive and not an object.